# Angular firestore

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I need help to draw my firestore schema.
Root collection
User - ID1 (athlete)
ID2 (coach) -> subColl (Page)
ID3

The user can be a trainer or an athlete

If it is trainer it saves the public data in another root  collection called

trainerInfo - ID (same as trainer ID example ID2)

Through trainerInfo the athlete can see the list of available trainers
With function:

```
fetchAvailableTrainer (): Observable <PublicTrainerInfo []> {
    return from (
      this.afs
        .collection <PublicTrainerInfo> (`trainerInfo`)
        .valueChanges ({idField: 'idField'})
    );
  }
```

When the trainer selects a trainer he can see his page which is a sub-collection of users with the function:

```
fetchTrainerPageFromAthlete (id): Observable <TrainerPage> {
    const collection = this.afs.collection <TrainerPage> (
      `users / $ {id} / trainerPage`
    );
    const trainerPage $ = collection.valueChanges ({idField: 'idField'}). pipe (
      map ((trainerPage) => {
        const trainerPage2 = trainerPage [0];
        return trainerPage2;
      })
    );
    returns trainerPage $;
  }
```

I wonder is it okay to expose the trainer ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not hide user ID. To restrict other users accessing the user data, you have to set firebase rule. [This document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth) will help you.